# How to change day of date in SQL server and set last day of month if the day does not exist in the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried using this

`dateadd(month, 0,  dateadd(day,(30-datepart(dd,'2015-02-28')),'2015-02-28'))`

to get the required output and instead of getting '2015-02-28' i get '2015-03-02'. How is it possible to change day of date in SQL and set last day of month if the day does not exist in the month ?

====Update with sample data =============

Note: Goal is not to get the last day of the month

If i want to change the day to 30 and if it's a month which has only 28 days. it should be the end of the month date. If not date should be 30th.

Changing the day to 30th
If Feb it should be - '2015-02-28'
If march it should be - '2015-03-30'
If April it should be - '2015-04-30'

Comment: you mean last day of last month ?. Please elaborate your question and add some sample data

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please [edit] to add sample data as DDL+DML and desired results.

Comment: It looks like you need a function that will replace the DAY part of a date.  Does my answer help?

Comment: Yes it does. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Replace Day portion of @OrigDate with @NewDay.
-- If the result would be beyond the end of the month, return the last day of the month

create function ReplaceDay ( @OrigDate date, @NewDay int ) 
returns date
as 
begin

declare @NewDate date

-- Deal with extreme cases, in case someone passes @NewDay = 7777 or @NewDay = -7777

if @NewDay < 1
  set @NewDay = 1

if @NewDay > 31 
  set @NewDay = 31

-- Subtract the DAY part of the original date from the new day.
-- Add that many days to the original date

-- Example:  if the original date is 2018-02-08 and you want to replace 08 with 17, then add 17-08=9 days

set @NewDate = DateAdd ( d, @NewDay-Day(@OrigDate), @OrigDate )

-- Have we ended up in the next month? 
-- If so subtract days so that we end up back in the original month.
-- The number of days to subtract is just the Day portion of the new date.

-- Example, if the result is 2018-03-02, then subtract 2 days

if Month(@NewDate)<>Month(@OrigDate)
  set @NewDate = DateAdd ( d, -Day(@NewDate), @NewDate )

return @NewDate

end

go

select dbo.ReplaceDay ( '2017-02-08', 17 ) -- Returns 2017-02-17 

select dbo.ReplaceDay ( '2017-02-08', 30 ) -- Returns 2017-02-28
```

Answer (score 3):

There exists a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) for this if your sql server version is 2012 or higher:

```
SELECT EOMONTH('2015-02-15')
```

returns `2015-02-28`

Comment: you can complete your answer by adding this for older sql server versions: `SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@mydate)+1,0))`

Comment: @B3S, feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually it's something else which i want to achieve. I have updated my question with sample data for reference. Sorry that i didn't provide it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

for sql server 2012 or higher versions please check HoneyBadger's answer.
for older versions:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@mydate)+1,0))
```