# How to update only days of a date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update all days in date column in table to special date?

I want change only day, no month, no year

My table:

```
id    RegisterDate
------------------
1      2001-01-18
2      2018-09-13
3      1999-04-28
4      2012-12-15
```

The result that I expect:

```
id    RegisterDate
------------------
1      2001-01-02
2      2018-09-02
3      1999-04-02
4      2012-12-02
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: what is `special date` ?

Comment: i want change only day, no month, no year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148323/how-to-change-day-of-date-in-sql-server-and-set-last-day-of-month-if-the-day-doe/49176669#49176669

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use `datefromparts()`:

```
update t
    set RegisterDate = datefromparts(year(RegisterDate), month(RegisterDate), 2);
```

Another method that works in older versions of SQL Server is:

```
update t
     set RegisterDate = dateadd(day, 2 - day(RegisterDate), RegisterDate);
```

As a side node:  there is no need to use string operations for this.  The built-in date/time functions are quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `eomonth` function that is available from SQL server 2012

```
update myTable
set RegisterDate = dateadd(dd, 2, eomonth(RegisterDate, -1))
```

Another way for all versions

```
update myTable
set RegisterDate = cast(convert(char(6), RegisterDate, 112)+'02' as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server version is higher than 2012, you can use the `FORMAT` function:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID INT,
    RegisterDate DATE 
)

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES (1, '2001-01-18'), (2, '2018-09-13'),
       (3, '1999-04-28'), (4, '2001-12-15');

UPDATE T
SET RegisterDate = FORMAT(RegisterDate,'yyyy-MM-') + '02'
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1163b/1*

Answer (score 0):

for **all versions** of SQL Server (since 2000)

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (dt DATE)
INSERT INTO @table 

SELECT GETDATE()-1
UNION ALL 
SELECT GETDATE()-2
UNION ALL 
SELECT GETDATE()-3
UNION ALL 
SELECT GETDATE()-5

 UPDATE @table
 SET dt = DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,dt),0))

 SELECT dt 
 FROM @table
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_date_add.asp